# Low resource fix for loose wood planks

Tags: repair, wood, floor

I just moved into an apartment with a row of loose wood planks along a central walkway. I'm only going to be here a few months, but I'd like to secure them somehow. Unfortunately for me, this house is in Brazil. Typical hardware stores like Lowe's or Home Depot are nowhere to be found and I don't speak the language well enough to have a conversation with a local hardware guy. There are plenty of Mom & Pop shops around with screws and wood shims, but I only have a very basic set of tools with me (an advanced utility knife). What are some methods to secure the wood blocks but not damage my feet when I walk over them?

[image]

Comment: Can you get your hands on some construction adhesive?

Comment: @JACK I'm not sure what that is. This might be a good answer, and I can try to figure out what it is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small job like that, I think construction adhesive would do the trick. Most local hardware stores should sell it. You'd need a caulking gun, about $5 bucks, to spread the adhesive. The adhesive comes in a cardboard tube similar to the one below. There are many different types.

[image]

Comment: This looks like it would adhesive the blocks to the floor (thank you!), but what about the spacing between the blocks? Should it be filled with the adhesive?

Comment: @Hooked - why do you care about the spacing?  Walking on a crack won't hurt your feet.